# Independent set greedy algorithm approximation

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, approximation

Ok so given a graph $ \mathrm G = (V,E) $ and we want to find a maximum independent set with the following algorithm:

```
Greedy(G):
S = {}
While G is not empty:
    Let v be a node with minimum degree in G
    S = union(S, {v})
    remove v and its neighbors from G
return S
```

Ok so i can think of examples where this algorithm fails, but can someone give the approximation ratio ? I have a feeling it has something to do with the maximum node degree but i cant figure it out

Comment: When you get an empty graph $nK_1$ on $n$ vertices you return an empty independent set that is infinitely worse than $n$.

Comment: See Halldórsson, M. M.; Radhakrishnan, J. (1997), "Greed is good: Approximating independent sets in sparse and bounded-degree graphs", Algorithmica, 18 (1): 145–163, CiteSeerX 10.1.1.145.4523, doi:10.1007/BF02523693.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm has an approximation ratio of $\Delta + 1$, where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree of the input graph $G$. That is, the resultant independent set, denoted as $S$, satisfies $|S| \geq \frac{1}{\Delta + 1} |\mathsf{OPT}|$, where $\mathsf{OPT}$ is a maximum independent set. Below is a proof.

**Proof.** Let $V$ be the set of vertices of $G$. To show that $|S| \geq \frac{1}{\Delta + 1}|\mathsf{OPT}|$, we only need to show
$$
|S| \geq \frac{1}{\Delta + 1} |V|
$$
For each vertex $v \in V \backslash S$, it is removed in the algorithm because some other vertex $u$ is put into $S$. Note that $v$ must be a neighbor of $u$ in this case. Charge $v$ to $u$. Therefore, the size of $V\backslash S$ satisfies
$$
|V \backslash S| = |V| - |S| \leq \Delta |S|
$$
which implies
$$
|V| \leq (1 + \Delta)|S| \Rightarrow |S| \geq \frac{1}{1 + \Delta}|V| \Rightarrow |S| \geq \frac{1}{1 + \Delta}|\mathsf{OPT}|
$$

Comment: I understand everything very well, except the part where you say "charge v to u" . I do not understand what you mean by that

Comment: @MarioZelic That is, for each vertex $v \in V \backslash S$, we associate it to a vertex $u \in S$.

Comment: Oh i get it so you want all vertices that belong to S, to be associated with the highest degree node right?

Comment: @MarioZelic No. I want each vertex in $V \backslash S$ to associate with exactly one vertex in $S$. Then the size of $V \backslash S$ can be bounded by $\sum_{u \in S} \delta(u) \leq \Delta |S|$, where $\delta(u)$ is the degree of $u$ in $G$.

Comment: Ok now its clear to me thank you very much

Comment: An approximation ratio of (Δ+2)/3 is possible.  Halldórsson, M. M.; Radhakrishnan, J. (1997), "Greed is good: Approximating independent sets in sparse and bounded-degree graphs", Algorithmica, 18 (1): 145–163, CiteSeerX 10.1.1.145.4523, doi:10.1007/BF02523693.

Comment: I think a tighter bound on the approximation ratio of $\frac{n}{t+1}$, can be obtained, where $t$ is defined as the average degree of the graph.
This is tight in the worst case.
For example, think of disjoint cliques. 
To my understanding, This result is due to V.K. Wei. although the only proof I found for it appears in 
"Lower Bounds on the Independence in Terms of the Degrees Number" By Jerrord R. Griggs.